# Is there a quick way to find missing end’s in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

We’ve all been there! Assuming enough code changed that a quick glance at `git diff` or the like doesn’t make it obvious, is there an easy way to find that missing `end` (short of switching to an indentation-based language like Python)?

FWIW, I use Sublime Text 2 as my editor.

Comment: vim syntax highlighting, and the ability to quickly reformat the  indentation of the code has taken away all that pain for me :-) Sublime Text is likely to have something similar, right?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 1.9, try the `-w` flag when running your ruby program.

```
# t.rb
class Example
  def meth1
    if Time.now.hours > 12
      puts "Afternoon"
  end
  def meth2
    # ...
  end
end

ruby t.rb  
=> t.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

ruby -w t.rb
=> t.rb:5: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'if' at 3
   t.rb:9: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 2
   t.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Source:

http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/12/ruby-19-can-check-your-indentation.html

Comment: Does this only only work if you use consistent indentation? (+1)

Comment: I removed all the whitespace and it didn't give me any mismatched identation errors so looks like the answer is yes.

Comment: Don't think there is an easy way to do that Augustin.

Comment: @augustin-riedinger I've found that, at least in some cases, you can run a Rails class from the command line using the -w option and it will find the mismatch before it gets bogged down in Rails specifics. E.g. ruby -w app/controllers/foo_controller.rb.

Comment: Sounds like a decent idea. Needs a little pipe of every `*.rb` files to run it, but its worth a try.

Comment: Note: `ruby t.rb -w` does not work. The flag has to go first.

Answer (score 4):

Edit (2023): this is now part of Ruby 3.2 and doesn‘t need to be required separately!

————————————

Edit (2022): the gem is now called [syntax_suggest](https://github.com/ruby/syntax_suggest) and is part of the Ruby standard library!

————————————

Since December 2020, there is also the [dead_end](https://github.com/zombocom/dead_end) gem which helps you detect missing `end`s.

The easiest way to get started is to install the gem:

```bash
gem install dead_end
```

and run it directly from your console, providing the file name to scan:

```bash
dead_end myfile.rb
```

This will provide you with a more helpful error message:

```
  43          if (col_idx - 1) % 3 == 0
  50            if !contains?(doc, node)
❯ 51              doc.add_child(node)
❯ 52              tree.
  53            end
  54          end
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/zombocom/dead_end) for more options.

Comment: That gem needs to be more popular, the sheer amount of mental agony I just saved is immense

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rails, you can run the problematic file specifically with the -w flag.

If you still can't find the offending mismatch, then my go-to way of solving this problem is just commenting out chunks of code until I can isolate the problematic area.

On OS X you can use command + / to comment out the highlighted piece of text.